# Saving data from API as string

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble saving the return output from my getLastMatchData() function outside of the function itself. Tried a bunch of different things but to no result. Any help would be very appreciated!

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const premier_League_Id = '39'
const tottenhamId = '47'


const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'REDACTED',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
};

function getLastMatchData() {
  fetch('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/fixtures?season=2022&team=47&last=1', options)
  .then(response => response.json().then(data =>{
    let generalLastMatchData = data['response'];
    let leagueName = generalLastMatchData[0]['league'].name;
    let teamNames = generalLastMatchData[0]['teams'];
    let homeTeam = teamNames['home'].name;
let awayTeam = teamNames['away'].name;
return [homeTeam, awayTeam];



 }))
}

const lastMatchNames = getLastMatchData();


console.log(lastMatchNames);
```

Comment: Protip: Use `async`/`await`. You also need to verify that `response` has `Content-Type: application/json` before you call `.json()`, otherwise it will throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the `getLastMatchData` function. Update it to this:

```js
function getLastMatchData() {
  // You were not returning the return value of the fetch call
  return fetch( "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/fixtures?season=2022&team=47&last=1", options).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    let generalLastMatchData = data["response"];
    let leagueName = generalLastMatchData[0]["league"].name;
    let teamNames = generalLastMatchData[0]["teams"];
    let homeTeam = teamNames["home"].name;
    let awayTeam = teamNames["away"].name;
   
    // This return value is for the Promise returned by the fetch call
    return [homeTeam, awayTeam];
  })
}
```

Use it like this:

```js
// data is an array that contains "homeTeam" on index 0 and "awayTeam" on index 1
getLastMatchData().then(data => console.log(data))
```

You need to use `.then` as the function returns a `Promise`.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're returning an array with two values `return [homeTam, awayTeam];`
I believe it should be:

```js
return { leagueName, teamNames, homeTeam, awayTeam };
```

then you can just log the returned value as you're currently doing!

also the function needs to be async function and you'll have to await it and await the function sending the request like so:

```
async function getLastMatchData() {
  return fetch( "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/fixtures?season=2022&team=47&last=1", options).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    let generalLastMatchData = data["response"];
    let leagueName = generalLastMatchData[0]["league"].name;
    let teamNames = generalLastMatchData[0]["teams"];
    let homeTeam = teamNames["home"].name;
    let awayTeam = teamNames["away"].name;
    return { leagueName, teamNames, homeTeam, awayTeam };
  })
}
```

Usage:

```
const res = await getLastMatchData();
console.log(res);
```